# group results by field on rails postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by

I'm studying rails at the moment and i'm trying to group results of a query by `field`.

the query is being created by:
`@orders = Order.includes(:product).where(user_id: current_user.id, paid: 0).group(:product_id)`

It works fine on sqlite (dev env) but it throws a fatal error while on production (postgreSQL).

Error is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "orders.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Hmm.. what am i doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group in postgres, you need to either directly select that column or you need to call an aggregate function that uses this column. `Count` is such an aggregate function and you can achieve that in Rails via

```
@product_counts = Order.where(user: current_user, paid: 0).group(:product_id).count
```

Postgres automatically executes `Count` on the column you grouped by, which is `product_id` in this case. This will give you a hash like this:

```
{ product_id => count }
```

For more information, see here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_group_by.htm